# Invalid attempt to read when no data is present

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqldatareader

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name;
    name = textBox5.Text;
    SqlConnection con10 = new SqlConnection("con strn");
    SqlCommand cmd10 = new SqlCommand("select * from sumant where username=@name");
    cmd10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",name);
    cmd10.Connection = con10;
    cmd10.Connection.Open();//line 7
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd10.ExecuteReader();
}

if ( textBox2.Text == dr[2].ToString())
{
    //do something;
}
```

When I debug until line 7, it is OK, but after that `dr` throws an exception:

> Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

I don't understand why I'm getting that exception, since I do have data in the table with username=sumant.

Please tell me whether the 'if' statement is correct or not. And how do I fix the error?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

You have to call [`DataReader.Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-data-sqlclient-sqldatareader-read) to fetch the result:

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd10.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read()) 
{
    // read data for single/first record here
}
```

`DataReader.Read()` returns a `bool` indicating if there are more blocks of data to read, so if you have more than 1 result, you can do:

```
while (dr.Read()) 
{
    // read data for each record here
}
```

Comment: besides that, you might want to try for the data to be null using dr.IsBDNull(0)

Answer (score 19):

You have to call `dr.Read()` before attempting to read any data. That method will return false if there is nothing to read.

Answer (score 10):

I just had this error, I was calling `dr.NextResult()` instead of `dr.Read()`.

Answer (score 8):

I would check to see if the SqlDataReader has rows returned first:

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd10.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.HasRows)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: in my case I had this, and though I have been using this elsewhere, in this particular scenario that produced this error, this did NOT stop the error from bubbling. My query resultant has rows, and yet the reader has no data. I really don't understand what is going on. Verified the query and parameters myself.

Answer (score 3):

I used the code below and it worked for me.

```
String email="";
    SqlDataReader reader=cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if(reader.Read()){
        email=reader["Email"].ToString();
    }

String To=email;
```

Comment: How does this solve OP's problem? You have entirely new code; where should they put this and what should it replace? Blocks of code without explanation are rarely useful for readers.

Answer (score 3):

I was having 2 values which could contain null values.

```
while(dr.Read())
 {
    Id = dr["Id"] as int? ?? default(int?);
    Alt =  dr["Alt"].ToString() as string ?? default(string);
    Name = dr["Name"].ToString()
 }
```

resolved the issue