# Get last ID from select query in C# WPF

Tags: c#, sql

I would like to get last selected person ID.

```
string personID = "SELECT PersonID FROM TestDatabase.[dbo].[Persons] where name LIKE 'XYZ%'";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(personID, con);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


var lastSelectedSingleClientPhoneId = reader.GetDecimal(0);
```

But unfortunately it did not work. I already tried to get int16, int32 and int64. When i use INSERT I can get the ID using the following select:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Insert command below:

```
string insertPerson = "INSERT INTO TestDatabase.[dbo].[Persons] (firstName,secondName) VALUES (@firstName,@secondName);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();"; 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertPerson, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", txt_firstName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secondName", txt_secondName.Text);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
reader.Read(); 
var lastInsertedPersontId = reader.GetDecimal(0);'
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'it did not work'? Does it throw?

Comment: Wait, are you trying to get the ID of a record you just inserted? That's not how you do that, use an [`OUTPUT` clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/).

Comment: can you show your `INSERT` statement.. you can do the Insert command and the Select `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` all in one statement for example 
`"INSERT INTO Properties (PropertyName,PropertyAddress,PropertyCity,PropertyState,PropertyZip,PropertyNotes)" +" values(@Name,@Address,@City,@State,@Zip,@Notes)SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";`

Comment: @cristobalito
"Invalid attempt to read when no data is present" - But this query return corectly personID.

Comment: you need to show your Insert command why are you posting partial code..  also doing a Select is not how you get the `@@SCOPE_IDENTITY`

Comment: Does the code referenced here (http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection) help? This question also seems to suggest it might - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147615/invalid-attempt-to-read-when-no-data-is-present

Comment: @MethodMan

`string insertPerson = "INSERT INTO TestDatabase.[dbo].[Persons] (firstName,secondName) VALUES (@firstName,@secondName);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertPerson, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", txt_firstName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secondName", txt_secondName.Text);

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
var lastInsertedPersontId = reader.GetDecimal(0);`

Comment: @ctrlaltdlt - can you put the code \ query into the question instead of the edits?

Comment: also `reader.GetDecimal(0)` is the PersonID in your table a Int32 or a Decimal

Comment: @MethodMan

In INSERT query i get the Decimal.

Comment: put your reader.Read() in a while loop also you need ExecuteScalar if you are returning 1 row.

Comment: you need to use output params as well take a look at some of these examples and refactor your code.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id

Comment: Now the question is confused - the first part talks about getting the result of a select while the second part seems to want the result of the insert? It sounds like you want the second - can you clarify the question?

Comment: I'm trying to make changes.

@cristobalito
I just want get the result of a select. In second part i just give example, beacuse when I use INSERT query i know how to get lastInstertPersonID.

Answer (score 0):

This should return all Persons beginning with 'XYZ' in the Persons database table.

```
string personID = "SELECT PersonID FROM TestDatabase.[dbo].[Persons] where name LIKE 'XYZ%'";

using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(personID, con))
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(0));
    }
}
```

I appreciate you're looking for a type to call `GetXXX`, but you can easily extend this pseudo-code to determine the appropriate type.

Comment: You have written similar code that I wrote in the question. It does not work. Loop cause that does not throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can try combining the two SQL statements as one CommandText value then use [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) to return the last inserted ID

```
string insertPerson = "INSERT INTO TestDatabase.[dbo].[Persons] (firstName,secondName) VALUES (@firstName,@secondName); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();"; 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertPerson, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", txt_firstName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secondName", txt_secondName.Text);
int personID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
/// ... convert integer value to a string or do something
```

You can also try this SQL statement as an alternative:

```
SELECT TOP 1 PersonID FROM Persons ORDER BY PersonID DESC;
```

Comment: I already tried that  - `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
I just want to get last selected personID from select query.

Comment: What is the data type of your primary key PersonID?

Comment: Int - I use SQL SMS 2012.

Comment: Try using the alternative SQL statement instead of SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: You're getting an error because the SQL statement does not return any value.

Comment: And this is my question how i can get this value from the select query? 

SCOPE_IDENTITY() - Returns the data perfectly when i INSERT data to DB, but i just want to get Person ID from select query.