# From combo box to textbox

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, datetimepicker

I can't figure out what's wrong or what the solution might me with my code it just gives me that it can't convert from string to int when i'm not using any ints only strings
I also can't figure out how to write and get the datetime to be placed back into the datetimepicker.

```
private void cbxProducts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = "Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = \"C:\\Users\\hannes.corbett\\Desktop\\Barcode Scanning\\Barcode Scanning\\BarcodeDB.mdf\"; Integrated Security = True";
            string Query = "SELECT * FROM Products where Name='" + cbxProducts.Text + "' ; ";
            SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
            SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

                string sBarcode = myReader.GetString("Barcodes");
                string sName = myReader.GetString("Name");
                var sDate = myReader.GetDateTime("EDate");
                string sQuantity = myReader.GetInt32("Quantity")).ToString();
                string sPrice = myReader.GetInt32("Price")).ToString();
                tbxBar.Text = sBarcode;
                tbxName.Text = sName;
                sDate = dateDate.Value;
                tbxPrice.Text = sPrice;
                tbxQua.Text = sQuantity;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

EDIT: [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TZ27.png)

EDIT 2: I get the error message

> "An invalid attempt was made to read when no data was available"

I have data in all of the strings in my database but i still get this error

Comment: Can you please provide the exact error message?
I think that either `string sQuantity = myReader.GetInt32("Quantity")).ToString();` or `string sPrice = myReader.GetInt32("Price")).ToString();` is wrong.
Check what data types you have in your db.

Comment: With this info we can only guess. My guess is that Price or Quantity or both is not int.

Comment: Cannot convert from string to int is what i get when i hover but i can't run the code since "Barcodes" and all of them is underlined with red

Comment: You should _always_ use [parameterized queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Alsu use `using` statement to dispose your connection and command automatically

Comment: your question was about why you got the error "can't convert from string to int" and the answer is because the methods `GetString`, `GetDateTime` and `GetInt32` works with field indexes instead of field names. Accept an answer and try to work out by yourself the solution to your program or make a new question about getting field values by name (also already answered here)

Comment: Well i haven't gotten an answer on my datatimepicker yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this it should work with columnnames or if you want to use columnIndex, do it the way @MtwStark described in his answer.

```
string sBarcode = myReader["Barcodes"].ToString();
string sName = myReader["Name"].ToString();
var sDate = myReader["EDate"];
string sQuantity = myReader["Quantity"].ToString();
string sPrice = myReader["Price"].ToString();
```

---

Concerning following error message

> "An invalid attempt was made to read when no data was available"

You have to call `myReader.Read()` first. (like someone asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147615/invalid-attempt-to-read-when-no-data-is-present))

```
while (myReader.Read()) {
    //do here whatever you want with the records returned from myReader
    string sBarcode = myReader["Barcodes"].ToString();
    string sName = myReader["Name"].ToString();
    var sDate = myReader["EDate"];
    string sQuantity = myReader["Quantity"].ToString();
    string sPrice = myReader["Price"].ToString();
    ...
}
```

Comment: When i do this myReader get's underlined with read and it says "method name expected"

Comment: Fixed it so i can run the code but i get the error 
"C # An invalid attempt was made to read when no data was available" when i try to choose from my combobox"

Comment: If your original question is answered, you should accept an answer here and create a new question.

Comment: is `Item` the default property? can you use `myReader["FieldName"]` instead of `myReader.item["FieldName"]`?

Comment: @MtwStark Yes, should work. The same applies to VB.NET. I never write `myReader.Item("FieldName")` i always use `myReader("FieldName")`.

Comment: @HannesCorbett the question is not "please make my program work" but "why I get this error?" so it is answered

Comment: @HannesCorbett I agree with MtwStark. Read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318267/ask-the-user-to-create-a-new-question-after-being-asked-in-comments/318313)

Answer (score 2):

you have to use the **index** of the column not the name

```
string sBarcode = myReader.GetString(IndexOfBarcodesColumn);
```

something like this

```
string sBarcode = myReader.GetString(0);
string sName = myReader.GetString(1);
var sDate = myReader.GetDateTime(2);
string sQuantity = myReader.GetInt32(3).ToString();
string sPrice = myReader.GetInt32(4).ToString();
```

or you can use field names directly from reader

```
string sBarcode = myReader.Item["Barcodes"];
string sName = myReader.Item["Name"];
var sDate = myReader.Item["EDate"];
string sQuantity = myReader.Item["Quantity"];
string sPrice = myReader.Item["Price"];
```

Comment: Ok, i'm new to doing things with databases so how do i find the index of the different columns?

Comment: if you use `SELECT * FROM Products` the order of columns is the one of creation in database, but you can get the columns in the order you want using something like `SELECT Barcodes, Name, EDate, Quantity, Price FROM Products` so barcodes will have index 0, Name index 1 and so on..

Comment: if this answer your question, please accept the answer

Comment: you have to use indexes instead of names

Comment: When i put .Item it can't find anything for it so .Item just gets underlined

Comment: @HannesCorbett SqlDataReader seems not to have an `Item`-method. Therefore this won't work.

Comment: What could i use instead any suggestions?

Comment: You wrote that my answer works. You seem to have a complete different  error now. But, like already mentioned: Instead of writing comments here, create a new question or at least edit your original question and add the error you get now.

Comment: SqlDataReader DO have th Item property [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f01t4cfy(v=vs.110).aspx) and it works as expected

Comment: @MtwStark I think we both are wrong and right. Have a look at [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/rss/1601495). Your syntax seems to be a mix of VB.NET and C#.

Comment: @MatSnow you are right I was using vb notation for parenthesis instead c# square brackets. I have now corrected it! :) I use vb and it was a ctrl-c/ctrl-v mistake ;)