# From Combobox to textbox error message

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, textbox

```
private void cbxProducts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = "Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = \"C:\\Users\\hannes.corbett\\Desktop\\Barcode Scanning\\Barcode Scanning\\BarcodeDB.mdf\"; Integrated Security = True";
            string Query = "SELECT Barcodes, Name, EDate, Quantity, Price FROM Products where Name='" + cbxProducts.Text + "' ; ";
            SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
            SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();


                    string sBarcode = myReader["Barcodes"].ToString();
                    string sName = myReader["Name"].ToString();
                    var sDate = myReader["EDate"];
                    string sQuantity = myReader["Quantity"].ToString();
                    string sPrice = myReader["Price"].ToString();
                    tbxBar.Text = sBarcode;
                    tbxName.Text = sName;
                    sDate = dateDate.Value;
                    tbxPrice.Text = sPrice;
                    tbxQua.Text = sQuantity;


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

When i try to use this code i just get the error message 
"An invalid attempt was made to read when no data was available" I do have data inside of my databse but it still doesn't work.

Comment: duplicate question....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147615/invalid-attempt-to-read-when-no-data-is-present

Comment: Exactly which line throws the error? What is the value of `myReader` when you debug? Isn't `myReader` supposed to be a list of values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid attempt to read when no data is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147615/invalid-attempt-to-read-when-no-data-is-present)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Reader` object fetches rows one by one and we need to tell it to bring the next row by using the `Read()` method.

You need to call `Read()` method of `SqlDataReader` object to read each row, if there is single row expected then you can do via an `if` otehrwise you would have to do in a `while` loop like:

```
while(myReader.Read())
{

                string sBarcode = myReader["Barcodes"].ToString();
                string sName = myReader["Name"].ToString();
                var sDate = myReader["EDate"];
                string sQuantity = myReader["Quantity"].ToString();
                string sPrice = myReader["Price"].ToString();
                tbxBar.Text = sBarcode;
                tbxName.Text = sName;
                sDate = dateDate.Value;
                tbxPrice.Text = sPrice;
                tbxQua.Text = sQuantity;
}
```

another thing is that you should not be doing string concatenation when creating queries, please consider using the parameterized queries as your code is open to [SQL Injection](https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjYjJTVs7jWAhXLBZoKHV93B3wQFggrMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSQL_injection&usg=AFQjCNGjvpn0N2cCPAW9gPFuxT2zyWOslw). You can read at [How to: Execute a Parameterized Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx) know how to write parameterized queries.