# Getting error "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present" while reading the value of a column of database

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqldatareader

While trying to read the value of a column, I am getting the error

> Invalid attempt to read when no data is present

Code:

```
If reader.HasRows Then
  name = reader("UserFirstName").ToString
  MsgBox(name)
End If
```

`reader.HasRows` is returning True, but while printing 'name', the error happens.

PS: `UserFirstName` column name exists in the table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid attempt to read when no data is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147615/invalid-attempt-to-read-when-no-data-is-present)

Comment: I don't agree with the duplicate vote. A) The duplicate refers to the same error but it is for a different language (OK minor) but B) The OP here is clearly misleaded by the HasRows call and thinks that it is enough to read the data. Needs to be explained and the duplicate has no mention of this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the [*Read*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=netframework-4.8) method before trying to get something out of a DataReader even if you call *HasRows* and it returns true.
The call to Read is required because after executing the command to get back the reader this object doesn't contain the data from the first record and only after a Read you can start to get your data.

```
If reader.Read() Then
  name = reader("UserFirstName").ToString
  MsgBox(name)
End If
```

As you can see, you don't need the call to *HasRows* because if there are no records to read the Read method returns directly false.